Are managed types always on the heap and garbage collected in .net 8 windows?
I am editing the question in order to demonstrate why having an answer is important.
First thing to know is that this is about gamedev, as a reminder game code must avoid feeding the garbage collector like the plague.
Please consider the question from the perspective of Godot using C# .net8 or whatever custom C# Unity is using. In the context of this question I believe they behave the same anyway.
A word of warning: Yes this is going to be about C# implementation details! Why? Because all gamedev in the world using C# rely on "C# implementation details" to make their game run without hitches! To be honest some might not even be aware of it but they do !
Meaning they avoid feeding the garbage collector because it will produce hitches in their frame rate.
Consider the following example:
private struct NormalStruct
{
    public bool MyBool;
}
...
public void TestMethod()
{
    // GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread measures allocations on the managed heap.
    long valA = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();
    NormalStruct normalStruct = new();
    long valB = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();

    long allocatedByteCount = valB - valA;

    // No allocation on the heap
    Assert.IsTrue(allocatedByteCount == 0);

    unsafe
    {
        // No warnings 
        NormalStruct* ptr = &normalStruct;
    }
}

It seems NormalStruct does not allocate any memory on the heap but on the stack instead. The little bit of unsafe code also tells us that NormalStruct is not a managed object because it would warn about it if it was.
So in this case I would think the normalStruct instance would escape garbage collection because it would be cleared when leaving the scope of TestMethod()
Now consider this other example
private struct ManagedStruct
{
    public bool MyBool;

    // Introducing a string in the struct to make it managed
    public string MyString;
}
...
public void TestMethod()
{
    long valA = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();
    ManagedStruct managedStruct = new();
    long valB = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();

    long allocatedByteCount = valB - valA;

    // Still no allocation on the heap
    Assert.IsTrue(allocatedByteCount == 0);

    unsafe
    {
        // Here a warning says that managedStruct is managed 
        //  Warning CS8500: This takes the address of, gets the size of, or declares a pointer to a managed type
        ManagedStruct * ptr = &managedStruct;
    }
}

The unsafe code here tells us managedStruct is indeed a managed object!
I took for granted that every managed object was allocated on the heap, turns out I was wrong, because GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread says otherwise.
Here is the question I need an answer to:
In the context I was describing earlier, does that mean the managedStruct instance is allocated on the stack therefore not being fed into the garbage collector?
If that is not enough to make sure how can I make sure it will be be fed into the garbage collector ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699740/is-it-true-that-garbage-collector-wont-collection-the-object-of-struct-type

Value types themselves are allocated on the stack, not the heap (but they might contain reference types members which are then on the heap, The refernce itself which is a bit like a pointer, is a part of the value type, but the reference type object itself is separate).

@wohlstad That is what I thought at first. But why would the structure become a managed type because a string was added ?
Does it become a reference type in this case ?

Mind that bool has a fixed length, while string does not. Which is what I would think triggers the warning. Also, strings in dotnet are ... complicated. It may be interned, maybe not ...

Nope @Fildor it does the same warning if you replace the string with a hand made classe like that: public class MyClass { public bool Bool; }

I think the term you are after are blittable. The former is blittable, since it is a value type that only contains blittable types. The later is not, since it contains a string that is not blittable.

^ this. String is not exactly like a custom class but neither are blittable.

@wohlstad That's gross simplification. In the current implementations, value types in local variables/parameters are on the stack or registers, everything else is on the heap. But that could easily change and is not part of the spec, for example it would be within spec to allocate all variables on the heap, or for the JIT to do escape analysis and allocate some reference objects on the stack where possible. See also The Stack Is An Implementation Detail

"Managed" just means the pointer is managed by GC as opposed to a raw native pointer (eg when coming from C/C++), and you shouldn't take the pointer of a managed object without fixed or a GCHandle as GC could move it underneath you. It has nothing to do with the location of the data per se.

@Charlieface even today, it isn't necessarily true; think "iterator blocks", "async methods", etc

@MarcGravell Yup, good example. My private "implementation" of .NET is fully conformant with the spec, but it stores objects on the Moon, which is made of cheese, and locals are on hand-written pizza order lists stacked in a pile. Latency is a bit of an issue, but otherwise see if you care.

@Charlieface I stand corrected. I thought the current implementation is more or less as I described, but anyway it is indeed a gross over-simplification.
